How to fix this cylic dependency in Spring?
I'm setting a Spring Security configuration with JWT and I need to create a custom authentication provider and a custom user details service, but in security config class is generating a cyclic dependency beetween them...
SecurityConfig.class
package io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.configuration;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.entities.CustomUserDetails;
import io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.services.AccountDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.access.BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
    private RSAPublicKey key;

    @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
    private RSAPrivateKey priv;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return customAuthenticationProvider::authenticate;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->auth
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.key).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(this.key).privateKey(this.priv).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

}

UserDetailsService.class
package io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.services;

import io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.entities.Account;
import io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.entities.CustomUserDetails;
import io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.exceptions.BadRequestException;
import io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.repositories.AccountRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class AccountDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        return loadUser(username);
    }

    private UserDetails loadUser(String username) throws BadRequestException {
        Optional<Account> userAccountOpt = accountRepository.findByLoginName(username);

        if (userAccountOpt.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

        Account account = userAccountOpt.get();

        return new CustomUserDetails(account.getLoginName(), account.getPasswordHash(), true, Set.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
    }
}

CustomAuthenticationProvider.class
package io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.configuration;

import io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.exceptions.BadRequestException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws BadRequestException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        System.out.println(password);
        System.out.println(userDetails.getPassword());

        if (userDetails == null || !passwordEncoder.matches(password, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Login or password incorrect.");
        }

        Authentication authenticated = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        return authenticated;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}

I tried to use @Lazy in UserDetailsService dependency in CustomAuthenticationProvider  and not resolved. Also tried to use @Lazy in SecurityConfig dependencies...
edit:
Sorry, I forgot the logs:
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfig (field private io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.configuration.CustomAuthenticationProvider io.github.felipeemerson.openmuapi.configuration.SecurityConfig.customAuthenticationProvider)
↑     ↓
|  customAuthenticationProvider defined in file [C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Documentos\Cursos\openmu-api\target\classes\io\github\felipeemerson\openmuapi\configuration\CustomAuthenticationProvider.class]
└─────┘


Usually Spring tells you the cyclic dependency including some possible solutions. Can you please share the log so we don't have to guess around or begin diving into your code without any clue in advance.

also authenticationJwTokenFilter that should be deleted, dont build home made security

Please [edit] the post and add the full stack trace.

sorry, I updated the question with the logs

Have you recognized that you put @Autowired to UserDetailsService in CustomAuthenticationProvider although you implicitly inject it through the constructor?

Also, have you tried to put the PasswordEncoder into its own config file, since both of your cyclic involved components rely on it - or better said, the one deploys it to the application while the other wants to inject it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The problem is that you want Spring to inject a CustomAuthenticationProvider into the SecurityConfig class:
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

But to create a CustomAuthenticationProvider Spring needs a PasswordEncoder
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

     public CustomAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
     }

and to create a PasswordEncoder Spring needs a fully initialized SecurityConfig (since SecurityConfig creates the PasswordEncoder).
The solution is to move the creation of the CustomAuthenticationProvider also into to SecurityConfig:
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder);
    }


Note that the @Component annotation on CustomAuthenticationProvider is no longer needed and should be removed.
